# Codeigniter Loading CSS/JS files at the top of the page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried to load the external css/js files at once by creating a `header.php` which is like

```
<style> @import url('<?=base_url()?>assets/css/style.css'); </style>
<style> @import url('<?=base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.css'); </style>
<style> @import url('<?=base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'); </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

In the controller file, I call these views like

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data['car'] = $this->car_model->findCar($id)->row();
    $this->load->view('index.php/car/show',$data);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Everything is fine but seems like all these files are loaded at the bottom of the page. I am facing difficulties like `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` while loading something like jQuery . I temporarily solved the problem by adding the script tag in the header of the specific view file.

How can I change if I want them to load at the top of the page, perhaps, in the `<header>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the order of the view loads:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $data['car'] = $this->car_model->findCar($id)->row();
    $this->load->view('index.php/car/show',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```